# Type hint function accepting a Union

Tags: python, python-typing, pyright

Here is my (much simplified) code:

```
def myfun(X:list[str|int]):
    for x in X:
        print(x)


X = [1,2,3]
myfun(X)
```

Pyright complains on the last line because I provide a list of `int` while the function requires `list[int|str]`.

- What is the best way to deal with that case?
- Is there a way to say pyright to accept "subtypes"?

Constraints:

- I do not want to define `X` as `X:list[str|int]=[1,2,3]` because, in my real case, I want `X` to be understood as list of `int`.
- I can call the function with `myfun(list[str|int](X))` but it is really annoying.

Comment: [mypy](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=06c2722b58c6eedf6f9ef005c2597fde) gives a more useful message: _""List" is invariant -- see https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#variance. Consider using "Sequence" instead, which is covariant."_

Comment: Hot take: you should prefer to type to interfaces like `Sequence` and `Map` rather than concrete implementations like `list` or `dict` anyway. Custom data structures are a thing some places.

Comment: In this specific case, it should be even `def myfun(X: Iterable[str | int]) -> None`, because you only iterate over the parameter, requiring the rest of `Sequence` protocol is unnecesary.

Comment: @JaredSmith If you write your comment as answer, I'll be glad to accept them.

Comment: @STerliakov If you write your comment as answer, I'll be glad to accept them. (can'I make two users in the same comment ?)

Comment: @LaurentClaessens done. Also "can'I make two users in the same comment" sadly no, it's a limitation of stack overflow's comment system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Program to *interfaces*, not *implementations*

-- [Gang of Four](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000SEIBB8)

This has been a staple chesnut of OOP lore for a long time (it dates back about [35 years now](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/306621/176474)). But if you've never worked in a statically typed system before, [it can be confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface) what that means. After all, Python has been object oriented since its inception, and until type hinting sayings like that were never really applicable other than in a very weak sense like using duck typing instead of `isinstance`.

But now we really need to make sure that we study the history of how to build software well in a statically typed system lest we be doomed to repeat it, and your question offers a great lens to examine this (thanks, btw).

First lets get a little background out of the way. We can't talk about why your code errors without defining *generics*. The technical definition is that a generic type is a type that is parameterized by other types. Which is cool and all, but perhaps a more intuitive way is to think of them as types that are *incomplete*, a sort of fill-in-the-blank type. I realize *you* may know this already, but not everyone reading this will get it.

When we talk about a value like a list `[]` it makes sense on it's own: it's a container and we can put all sorts of things inside it, the fact it's empty right now doesn't really matter. But types are *categories*, so it really doesn't make sense to talk about the *type* (category) of 'List' without saying a List *of* something specific. Types like `List` are generic in that you need another type to complete them, you can have a `List[int]` or a `List[Tuple[int, int]]` or whatever.

Depending on the circumstances generics vary in how they handle subtype relationships in their parameters, this variance is the source of your problem as commenter jonrsharpe already helpfully pointed out. Explaining variance is outside the scope of this answer, but in addition to [the official mypy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#variance-of-generics) you might find [this resource](https://acko.net/blog/on-variance-and-extensibility/) helpful. Because you use the union type `str|int` that means that `str` and `int` are both subtypes of that union, and so the variance rules apply when the union is passed as a parameter to a generic type.

TL;DR because of how mypy treats the variance of different generic container types you want to use a different one than `List`, the error message helpfully suggests `Sequence` instead, as another commenter STerliakov points out you only really need `Iterable`.

But let's get back to my opening quote and talk about *why* the system is structured that way.

*Part* of the reason I presume is to encourage the best practice I opened with: when designing an API down to and including function signatures, you really want to specify the bare minimum contract that the function needs to do it's work. If the only thing your function needs is an object with a `getTimeStamp` method that returns an integer, you really don't want to write `def my_fun(x: SomeClass):` because now `my_fun` is *tightly coupled* to that class. If you want to refactor `SomeClass` and move the `getTimeStamp` functionality to `SomeOtherClass` now every call site of `my_fun` is **broken** and needs to be changed.

Refactoring tools are helpful but not really a solution: what if this is a published library on PyPI? Now what should be an internal implementation detail has *leaked* and you have a breaking change major version semver bump. Instead, you want to use the type system to say "this function expects that 'x' will be an object with a getTime method that returns an integer", and *any* object that qualifies is fine (N.B. this also greatly simplifies writing unit tests for the code and obviates the need for a lot of unnecessary mocking).

So for your code which iterates a linear number of integers or strings you want to use a type that describes "something that contains integers or strings and works with a for loop":

```
from typing import Iterable

def my_fun(xs: Iterable[int|str]):
    for x in xs:
        print(x)

foo = {1, 2, 3} # set
bar = [1, 2, 3] # list
baz = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3} # dict

my_fun(foo)
my_fun(bar)
my_fun(baz)
```

You can see now that the *concrete* data structure doesn't matter, we can pass in anything that conforms, even a custom user-defined object with `__iter__` and `__next__` methods! The typechecker encourages you to do this by making it more cumbersome if you don't and instead use a concrete data type like `List`, via the generic variance rules.

Well, almost. See I'm assuming you typed it that way because you want to be able to pass in `[1, 'a']` and not just `[1, 2]` or `['a', 'b']`, and this cool trick fails in mypy when we use a heterogeneous structure:

```
oops = [1, 'a']
my_fun(oops)
```

You will get an error that you supplied `List[object]` where it expected `Iterable[str|int]`. Which unlike the best-practice-encouraging generic variance rules is [arguably a flaw in the mypy typechecker](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/12009#issuecomment-1016081515), I note that my IDE gets this correct and does not show that error because it's using pyright as the LSP (I see you tagged the question pyright, so you may be ok). So that stinks, and you would need to explicitly hint `oops` to be `oops: Iterable[str|int] = [1, 'a']`, which is unfortunate.